# How to get OS option (dual boot) when i have two OSs on separate disks?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I have two HDDs on my PC, one has Win7 and the other, Ubuntu 12.04 (with boot). To choose which OS to use, i have to change my boot priorities from BIOS. How can I get it to ask me which OS to boot rather than me changing that again and again since I have multiple users on Win7?

Comment: Install "grub": https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing

Comment: Are both systems installed in BIOS boot mode? Or is one UEFI and one BIOS. That always requires you to boot from UEFI menu. Post this: `sudo parted -l` and results of `sudo update-grub`.

Answer (score 0):

There should not be any issue loading from different disks (at least with grub2). Here is an easy tool you can use to edit grub https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer.

Just add a new entity and choose your partition from the other disk